# How to make complex 'map' and 'flat' with RxJS in true functional style?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, rxjs

RxJS and TypeScript offer great functional programming capabilities.
So when it makes sense I try to practice it.
But today I failed to write quite simple mapping logic in a functional style.
I still believe it's possible to describe it in **true functional way, yet brief, elegant and easy-to-read**. What would be such a code?

Here is a stackblitz playground:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-functional-challenge?file=index.ts

Full copy of the source code is also under the spoiler.

```js
import { Observable, of, identity } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

interface TimeWindow{
  Start: number,
  End: number
}

interface Schedule{
  Monday: TimeWindow[],
  Tuesday: TimeWindow[],
}

let schedule$: Observable<Schedule>; // input varible
let timeWindows$: Observable<{Day: string, Time: string}[]>; // result variable

schedule$ = of({
  Monday: [{Start: 9, End: 11}, {Start: 15, End: 17}],
  Tuesday: [{Start: 8, End: 10}, {Start: 14, End: 16}],
});

// conversion
// how to rewrite it into 100% functional style, yet still easy to read?

timeWindows$ = schedule$.pipe(
  map(schedule => [
    ... mapToTimeWindows('Monday', schedule.Monday),
    ... mapToTimeWindows('Tuesday', schedule.Tuesday,)
  ])
);

function mapToTimeWindows(day: string, timeWindows: TimeWindow[]): {Day: string, Time: string}[]{
  const convertTime = (hour: number) => hour.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00';

  return timeWindows.map(item => ({
    Day: day,
    Time: convertTime(item.Start) + ' - ' + convertTime(item.End)      
  }));
}

// expected result
// converted to console in functional style

timeWindows$.pipe(
  mergeMap(identity),
  map(item => item.Day + ':  ' + item.Time),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe();


/*
Monday:  09:00 - 11:00
Monday:  15:00 - 17:00
Tuesday:  08:00 - 10:00
Tuesday:  14:00 - 16:00
*/
```

Comment: It is noteworthy that RX only makes sense in the context of event based asynchronous computations, because an observable is basically an abstraction for event delegation.

Comment: The least functional thing about your code is the use of `let` but that would be trivial to change. It doesn't have anything to do with RX, it's about referential transparency

Answer (score 2):

[Link to the playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-functional-challenge-hrdwqm?file=index.ts)

```js
const convertTime = (hour: number) => hour.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":00";

timeWindows$ = schedule$.pipe(
  map(schedule =>
    Object.keys(schedule).flatMap(weekDay =>
      schedule[weekDay].map(item => ({
        Day: weekDay,
        Time: convertTime(item.Start) + " - " + convertTime(item.End)
      })
     )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally leave heavy harmory (such as rxjs) for async/side effects tasks,
while I leverage tools such as `Ramda` for more pure and data transformations kind of work

```js
const pad = (h) => `${h.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
  
const toTimeWindows = ([Day, windows]) => R.map(
  ({ Start, End }) => [Day, `${pad(Start)} - ${pad(End)}`],
  windows,
);

const fromSchedule = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.chain(toTimeWindows),
  R.map(R.join(':  ')),
);

// ==== //

const schedule = {
  Monday: [{ Start: 9, End: 11 }, { Start: 15, End: 17 }],
  Tuesday: [{ Start: 8, End: 10 }, { Start: 14, End: 16 }],
};

console.log('schedule', fromSchedule(schedule));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Here is the RxJS equivalent :)

```js
const schedule = {
  Monday: [{ Start: 9, End: 11 }, { Start: 15, End: 17 }],
  Tuesday: [{ Start: 8, End: 10 }, { Start: 14, End: 16 }],
};

// ==== //

const { pairs } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap, map, toArray } = rxjs.operators;

const pad = (h) => `${h.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
  
const toTimeWindows = ([Day, windows]) => windows.map(
  ({ Start, End }) => [Day, `${pad(Start)} - ${pad(End)}`],
);

pairs(schedule).pipe(
  mergeMap(toTimeWindows),
  map((data) => data.join(':  ')),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'schedule'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.3/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha512-Pca6Cn5CDh0NawlgV72T8bBDWCx6WjXzonw6AYigdJrgovaD1GkhTfpT9KDHbcNbN/6qWVsJqdkQwA7kaNdYeg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```